# child_process.spawn() isn't waiting for child node process to complete

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following works as expected, waiting for 3 seconds before exiting:

```
child_process.spawn( 'sleep', [3] );
```

but this is exiting immediately, not waiting for 3 seconds as it should (and as it does when this command is run directly:

```
child_process.spawn( 'node', ['-e', '"setTimeout(null, 3000);"'] );
```

Any ideas as to why? Thanks.

**Edit:** `spawnSync()` behaves the same way in both cases. Also, I'm not expecting the `spawn()` function to block, I'm expecting the node process to wait for its children to exit before exiting itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the double quotation marks. That makes your program execution just a string rather than a `setTimeout()` function call. Use this instead:

```
child_process.spawn( 'node', ['-e', 'setTimeout(null, 3000);'] );
```

Note the removal of the double quotation marks around `setTimeout()`.

With the double quotation marks, it's effectively the same as running this from the command line (assuming a Unix-like operating system/shell):

```
'node' '-e' '"setTimeout(null, 3000);"'
```

Try it and you'll see it returns right away because the last argument is just a string value that doesn't need to be parsed and executed. Then try this:

```
'node' '-e' 'setTimeout(null, 3000);'
```

That will wait three seconds like you expect.